# How can I get the Breeze nuget package to install?

Tags: breeze

I'm having some dependency issues installing Breeze.

I installed the ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 update into Visual Studio 2012 and then installed Angular into a freshly made ASP.NET Web API project and when I try to install the Breeze nuget package it bombs out with this error.

> Install failed. Rolling back... Install-Package : Failed to add
>   reference to 'System.Web.Http.OData'. At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  Breeze.WebApi
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Here is the full install attempt from the command line including all the dependencies it is attempting to resolve.

> ```
> Install-Package Breeze.WebApi
> Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi'.
> Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost (≥ 4.0.20710.0 && < 4.1)'.
> Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (≥ 1.0.0.0)'.
> Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 4.0.20710.0 && < 4.1)'.
> Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (≥ 4.0.20710.0 && < 4.1)'.
> Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Net.Http (≥ 2.0.20710.0 && < 2.1)'.
> Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 4.5.6)'.
> Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData'.
> Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.OData (≥ 5.2.0 && < 6.0.0)'.
> Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Spatial (= 5.2.0)'.
> Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.Edm (= 5.2.0)'.
> Attempting to resolve dependency 'WebActivator'.
> Attempting to resolve dependency 'EntityFramework (≥ 4.4 && < 6.0)'.
> Attempting to resolve dependency 'Q'.
> You are downloading Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData from Microsoft....
> Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 4.0.1'.
> Successfully installed 'WebActivator 1.5.3'.
> Successfully installed 'Q 0.9.2'.
> Successfully installed 'Breeze.WebApi 1.2.8'.
> Successfully removed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 4.0.0' from CrashBangZoom.WebApi.
> Install failed. Rolling back...
> Install-Package : Failed to add reference to 'System.Web.Http.OData'.
> At line:1 char:16
> + Install-Package <<<<  Breeze.WebApi
>     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have a problem - I just installed Angular (stable) and Breeze (stable) into a TestMVC project using NuGet on Windows 8 x64 machine. There is an acceptance prompt that displays before it is installed (OData-related) and it does use powershell to install - so you should check to make sure that is installed.

```
------- Installing...Breeze.WebApi 1.2.8 -------
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost (≥ 4.0.20710.0 && < 4.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure (≥ 1.0.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (≥ 4.0.20710.0 && < 4.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (≥ 4.0.20710.0 && < 4.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Net.Http (≥ 2.0.20710.0 && < 2.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 4.5.6)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.OData (≥ 5.2.0 && < 6.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'System.Spatial (= 5.2.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Data.Edm (= 5.2.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'WebActivator'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'EntityFramework (≥ 4.4 && < 6.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Q'.
Added file 'System.Web.Http.OData.dll' to folder 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.1\lib\net40'.
Added file 'System.Web.Http.Odata.xml' to folder 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.1\lib\net40'.
Added file 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.1.nuspec' to folder             'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.1'.
Added file 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.1.nupkg' to folder 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.1'.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 4.0.1'.
Added file 'WebActivator.dll' to folder 'WebActivator.1.5.3\lib\net40'.
Added file 'WebActivator.1.5.3.nuspec' to folder 'WebActivator.1.5.3'.
Added file 'WebActivator.1.5.3.nupkg' to folder 'WebActivator.1.5.3'.
Successfully installed 'WebActivator 1.5.3'.
Added file 'q.js' to folder 'Q.0.9.2\content\Scripts'.
Added file 'q.min.js' to folder 'Q.0.9.2\content\Scripts'.
Added file 'NuGet.exe' to folder 'Q.0.9.2'.
Added file 'Q.0.9.2.nuspec' to folder 'Q.0.9.2'.
Added file 'Q.0.9.2.nupkg' to folder 'Q.0.9.2'.
Successfully installed 'Q 0.9.2'.
Added file 'BreezeWebApiConfig.cs.pp' to folder 'Breeze.WebApi.1.2.8\content\App_Start'.
Added file 'breeze.debug.js' to folder 'Breeze.WebApi.1.2.8\content\Scripts'.
Added file 'breeze.intellisense.js' to folder 'Breeze.WebApi.1.2.8\content\Scripts'.
Added file 'breeze.min.js' to folder 'Breeze.WebApi.1.2.8\content\Scripts'.
Added file 'Breeze.WebApi.dll' to folder 'Breeze.WebApi.1.2.8\lib'.
Added file 'Irony.dll' to folder 'Breeze.WebApi.1.2.8\lib'.
Added file 'readme.txt' to folder 'Breeze.WebApi.1.2.8'.
Added file 'install.ps1' to folder 'Breeze.WebApi.1.2.8\tools'.
Added file 'Breeze.WebApi.1.2.8.nuspec' to folder 'Breeze.WebApi.1.2.8'.
Added file 'Breeze.WebApi.1.2.8.nupkg' to folder 'Breeze.WebApi.1.2.8'.
Successfully installed 'Breeze.WebApi 1.2.8'.
Removed reference 'System.Web.Http.OData.dll' from project 'MvcApplication1'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully removed 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 4.0.0' from MvcApplication1.
Added reference 'System.Web.Http.OData' to project 'MvcApplication1'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 4.0.1' to MvcApplication1.
Added reference 'WebActivator' to project 'MvcApplication1'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully added 'WebActivator 1.5.3' to MvcApplication1.
Added file 'q.min.js' to folder 'Scripts'.
Added file 'Scripts\q.min.js' to project 'MvcApplication1'
Added file 'q.js' to folder 'Scripts'.
Added file 'Scripts\q.js' to project 'MvcApplication1'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully added 'Q 0.9.2' to MvcApplication1.
Added file 'breeze.min.js' to folder 'Scripts'.
Added file 'Scripts\breeze.min.js' to project 'MvcApplication1'
Added file 'breeze.intellisense.js' to folder 'Scripts'.
Added file 'Scripts\breeze.intellisense.js' to project 'MvcApplication1'
Added file 'breeze.debug.js' to folder 'Scripts'.
Added file 'Scripts\breeze.debug.js' to project 'MvcApplication1'
Added file 'BreezeWebApiConfig.cs' to folder 'App_Start'.
Added file 'App_Start\BreezeWebApiConfig.cs' to project 'MvcApplication1'
Added reference 'Breeze.WebApi' to project 'MvcApplication1'
Added reference 'Irony' to project 'MvcApplication1'
Added file 'packages.config'.
Successfully added 'Breeze.WebApi 1.2.8' to MvcApplication1.
Executing script file 'C:\Users\andrew\Documents\Visual Studio     2012\Projects\packages\Breeze.WebApi.1.2.8\tools\install.ps1'.
Removed file 'System.Web.Http.OData.dll' to folder 'C:\Users\andrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.0\lib\net40'.
Removed file 'System.Web.Http.Odata.xml' to folder 'C:\Users\andrew\Documents\Visual Studio     2012\Projects\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.0\lib\net40'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\andrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.0\lib\net40'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\andrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.0\lib'.
Removed file 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.0.nuspec' to folder 'C:\Users\andrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.0'.
Removed file 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.0.nupkg' to folder 'C:\Users\andrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.0'.
Removed folder 'C:\Users\andrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData.4.0.0'.
Successfully uninstalled 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData 4.0.0'.
==============================
```

Comment: Hm, I must have some sort of dependency issue.  I'm not sure where I messed things up though.  This is a Windows 7 X64 machine.  It does have Powershell installed.  I'm running VS2012 as admin.  Do you have that WebTools update installed?

Comment: It seems as if the installation of the latest version of Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.OData is the actual issue as that fails if I try to install it separately.  I'll close this and re-ask about that.